# Can get, put & remove element in HashMap without iteration cause ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrentmodification

I have a static hashMap, shared with multiple threads. I am not iterating the map at all but just uses the `get`, `put`, `remove`. Is it safe from `ConcurrentModificationException` ?

The method looks like this

```
private static Map<Long, Integer> TRACKER = new HashMap<Long,Integer>();
public static void track(Long tid, boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            if (TRACKER.containsKey(tid)) {
                TRACKER.put(tid, TRACKER.get(tid) + 1);
            } else {
                TRACKER.put(tid, 1);
            }
        } else {
            Integer n = TRACKER.get(tid);
            if (n != null) {
                n = n -1;
                if (n == 0) {
                    TRACKER.remove(tid);
                } else {
                    TRACKER.put(tid, n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing in the code you're showing us here to cause a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Nothing will cause a concurrent modification exception...and that's *bad,* because concurrent modification is happening, and breaking things, but it can't figure it out and throw an exception to warn you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe from `ConcurrentModificationException`?

It is safe from `ConcurrentModificationException`.  That exception is only thrown by methods that iterate (in some sense) the map or one of its views using a conventional iterator or a spliterator.

However, since `HashMap` is not a thread-safe class, if you use it from multiple threads without proper external external synchronization, bad things can happen.  These include (in order of increasing badness)

1. The `size()` method reporting the wrong value.
2. Entries mysteriously disappearing, either temporarily or permanently.
3. Possible NPEs and other unchecked exceptions.
4. Possible infinite loops due to an unfortunate sequence of operations by multiple threads creating a loop in a hash chain.

Your example code *is unsafe* ... but you won't get a "fast fail" `ConcurrentModificationException`.  Instead you are likely to get inexplicable errors at "random" times that are difficult to reproduce.

Answer (score 5):

If multiple threads are performing `get`, `put` & `remove` operations on a `HashMap`, without proper synchronization, some bad things like size() reporting missing / lost entries, unexpected NPEs ... even infinite loops may happen.

HashMap [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) says -

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A
>   structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
>   more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an
>   instance already contains is not a structural modification.) ...

Thanks Stephen.

Comment: You probably could update the values concurrently without synchronization after reading those docs, But I can't imaging the mechanisms needed to do the checks required to update the value without accidentally putting a new value. It would have to be incredibly contrived.