# Do I need ConcurrentHashMap if I only call get, put, remove with thread id being the key and never iterate the map?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

[Original Question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213393/can-get-put-remove-elemetn-in-hashmap-without-iteration-cause-concurrentmodif?noredirect=1#comment91379034_52213393) but this time slightly different scenario.

I have a static hashMap, shared with multiple threads. I am not iterating the map and don't care about the size of the map. I only use the `get`, `put`, `remove` in the map. Each thread may call `someClass.track(true)` or `someClass.track(false)`. I want to track when a thread enters a method (increment #) and exit a method (decrements #) for each thread.

Is it sufficient to use just a HashMap? Or I have to use a ConcurrentHashMap to guarantee getting a correct value from the `track` method?

The method looks like this

```
private static Map<Long, Integer> TRACKER = new HashMap<Long,Integer>();
public static Integer track(boolean b) {
    long tid = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    if (b) {
        if (TRACKER.containsKey(tid)) {
            TRACKER.put(tid, TRACKER.get(tid) + 1);
        } else {
            TRACKER.put(tid, 1);
        }
    } else {
        Integer n = TRACKER.get(tid);
        if (n != null) {
            n = n -1;
            if (n == 0) {
                TRACKER.remove(tid);
            } else {
                TRACKER.put(tid, n);
            }
        }
    }
    return TRACKER.get(tid);
  }
```

Comment: here is the [answer to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52213856/9949315)

Comment: @Anthony C You should focus on the requirement as you ask your question. According to the old question, you try to guess very specific issues that may never happen. But this question is already much clearer.

Comment: It's something very simple, it tracks # of calls enter some specific methods (possibly recursive) per thread. It calls `track(true) ` at the first line of the method and call `track(false)` at the last line of the method

Comment: I thought the answers to the previous question did a perfectly adequate job of telling you this was dangerously broken, complete with references to the api doc that says not to do this. what is left that needs clarifying?

Comment: @NathanHughes, just wanted to know if ConcurrentHashMap is enough to fix it or need something more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may modify the map while you read it. So for at least this reason you should consider to use `ConcurrentHashMap` or use an explicit synchronization mechanism as [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is not designed to be used in this way :

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

Or use `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Note that `ConcurrentHashMap` may not fit as you want to get the value associated to a key at a specific instant according to the timeline.  As with `ConcurrentHashMap`, retrieval operations are not blocking, these reflect the last "known information" that is [not necessarily the last chronological information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) :

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals
>   reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
>   holding upon their onset.

In a general way, having the exact information at the `I` instant depends really on your requirement.  You don't explain yours but whatever, it doesn't matter because according to your actual code, the method is accessed concurrently by threads that don't manipulate the same key/value. So, this `ConcurrentHashMap` particularity is not a problem.
So it seems a very good use case for `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: You say `thread B with the same tid can enter the same statement`.  If tid is actually a thread id as he says, how could this happen?  You would need to have multiple threads with the same id right?

Comment: @Eric Petroelje I though of the same thing. I rewrited my answer. While as the OP performs concurrent reading/writing on  the Map, the synchronization remains needed.